# weird behavior angularjs & php

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

can someone tell me why this returns false:

```
if('{{shopController.shop.shop_id}}.xml' == '89.xml')
```

even if `{{shopController.shop.shop_id}} is 89 (string)`

I'm trying to

```
echo nl2br(htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents($xml_file)));
```

Comment: In what context is this if statement? Is it in PHP? is it in Angular? If it's in PHP, then PHP runs on the server and your angular code will run on the client, it just won't work.

Comment: There's not enough information to give an informed answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use something like

```
if($scope.shop_id+'.xml' === '90.xml')
```

`{{}}` are to be used in template files only. not in `js` files.

PS: I assumed this to be client side code.